# trouble query finding the entry with the highest number

Tags: sql

I need some help a query. For each movie in my database that has at least one rating, I need to find the highest number of stars that movie has recieved. The data I want the query to return is movie, title and the number of stars sorted by movie title.

The tables I am working with are the following:

```
Movie(mID int, title text, year int, director text);
Reviewer(rID int, name text);
Rating(rID int, mID int, stars int, ratingDate date);
```

Comment: You want all movies where at least one of its reviews has a score equal to the best score received so far?

Comment: each movie has different ratings(stars). I want to recieve each movie that has the most stars for that movie. For example titanic would have two rating, one with four stars and one with five. I want the query to only display the entry with five stars as it is the one with the most stars for this movie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  Movie.*,
  Rating.Stars
FROM
  Movie
INNER JOIN
  Rating
    ON Movie.mid = Rating.mid
WHERE
  Rating.Stars = (SELECT MAX(Stars) FROM Rating)
```

*(Wow, so hard to do this on an iPhone.)*

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
select m.title, max(stars) 
from movie m join rating r on (m.mid = r.mid)
group by m.mid, m.title
order by m.title;
```

Comment: I need to display each occurence of each movie that has the most stars

Comment: this seems to work but could someone provide furthur explanation to what the GROUP BY statement used here does. Without it the query doesn't return the proper information I am after.